# What is the nonlinear transformation assumed by the gaussian (rbf) kernel?

Tags: normal-distribution, nonlinear, kernel-trick

A common kernel choice is the gaussian kernel:
$ k(x,x^{'}) = \exp \big( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\| x - x^{'} \|^2 \big)$

This implies a transformation on $x$, and equally on $x^{'}$. What is it?